# server premision resets for laravel storage folder

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

i have a problem that my server premisions on storage folder resets like every 2 days . so i run these commands and it gets fixed :

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache

chmod -R 775 storage 
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

the problem is that the error comes again like below :

```
the stream or file could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: permission denied
```

so i took an screen shot from before running commands and after that and its :
[image]

so before running storage owns by :

```
drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data      4096 Nov  7 02:00  storage
```

and after

```
drwxrwxr-x  6 root     www-data      4096 Nov  7 02:00  storage
```

Comment: Do you have a git repository on the server?

Comment: yes its a git repo @BABAKASHRAFI

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the git. When run for example `git pull`, it changes the owner of the files to the root user. You can run git command via www-data user or change the owner of files to www-data after each git command.

Example of `git pull` as a www-data user

```
sudo -u www-data git pull origin master
```

Comment: at first i though the same . so i didnt pull the project for like 1 week but the same thing happened again and the owner changed . any idea ?

Comment: Do you have any schedulers that run every 2 weeks? Maybe an error occurs in one of its commands and it tries to write an error in the laravel.log.